# How can I have ghc invoke the linker differently than its default configuration?

Tags: haskell, linker, ghc

I can pass options to the linker using `cc` with the `-Wl` option.  For example:

```
cc -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
```

That will invoke the linker with `-rpath /usr/local/lib`

How can I do the same with ghc?

Also how can I also direct `ghc` to use a different linker than its default linker?  For instance, if `ghc` is configured to use `/usr/bin/ld`, how can I tell it to use `/usr/local/bin/ld` instead?  One way to do that with `cc` is:

```
cc -B/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Haven't tried this, but according [the ghc manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/options-phases.html), `-optl` should let you pass options, and `-pgml` should let you use a different linker.

Comment: These are good hints - thanks. The docs organization don't make it easy to search all the options very easily. There's some idiosyncracies with these options I'm trying to work through (e.g., -optl -B/usr/local/bin or -optc -B/usr/local/bin don't seem to "work" - odd error: /usr/local/bin/settings: openFile: does not exist).  I'll work through the oddities and craft an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do `ghc -optl-rpath -optl/usr/local/lib`
and `ghc -optc-B/usr/local/bin`.